# A very interesting thing when submit a simple form to create new model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a **Rails v2.3.2** app.

I have a **Model** with validations:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates_presence_of :name, :email

  # Please notice this method
  def pwd=(pwd)
      encrypted_pwd = pwd + randn(127)
      self.password = encrypted_pwd  
  end
end
```

**NOTE:** The above model has attributes: `name`, `email` and `password` (not `pwd`), where `password` is not directly get and store to database, instead, the user input `pwd` value will be encrypted and then store as `password` in database. In database table, the column(attribute) is `password`. I use `def pwd=(pwd) ...` to achieve this.

My **Controller**:

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @person = Person.new(params[:person])
     if @person.save
       redirect_to persons_path
     else
       render :action=> :new
     end
   end

   def new
     #empty
   end

   def index
     @persons = Person.all
   end
end
```

The **view** (`views/persons/new.html.erb`):

```
 <% form_for :person, @person, :url => persons_url, :html=>{:method=>:post} do |f| %>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :email %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>password:</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :pwd %></td> <!--NOTE: here I use :pwd not :password-->
      </tr>
    </table>
    <%= f.submit "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

The **interesting & strange** thing is , if in the view form, I input values to every field then submit the form, **my new instance created successfully**.

**BUT**, if I leave `name` and `email` **empty**, **only** input `password` field (which will be `pwd` value) in the form, **then the application got broken**, with the error message:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `pwd' for #<Person:0xa0ec0e0>) on line #25 of app/views/persons/new.html.erb:
22:       </tr>
23:       <tr>
24:         <td>password:</td>
25:         <td><%= f.text_field :pwd %></td>
26:       </tr>
27:     </table>
```

I also tried from **Rails console**, I can create and save object like:

```
Person.new(:name=>'John', :email=>'john@gmail.com', :pwd=>'test')
```

So:

**1. Why** I can successfully create a model instance if all fields have been filled with values in the form, **BUT I got that error** when I leave `name` and `email` empty but input value to password(pwd) field?

**2. Why** I do not get error message which complains the `name` and `email` should not be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your model is missing an attribute reader (getter) for `pwd`.

Here's what's happening:

As `name` and `email` are required (courtesy of `validates_presence_of :name, :email`), when you do not enter them and submit the form, an error occurs and the form is rendered again and the view wants to fill the `pwd` field, but as you haven't defined it, you get that error message: `undefined method 'pwd' for #<Person:0xa0ec0e0>`.

So you can add a getter like this to your `Person` class:

```
def pwd
  "" # or whatever you like
end
```

And your form should work again. If you want your model to remember the unencrypted password when an error occurs, you can have something like this instead:

```
def pwd=(pwd)
  @pwd = pwd
  encrypted_pwd = pwd + randn(127)
  self.password = encrypted_pwd
end

def pwd
  @pwd || ""
end
```

Comment: Then, Why the first time when I load the new.html.erb page, it does not complain on ':pwd' ?? and I can even create a person instance if I fill all the fields in the form, can you also explain this??

Comment: Because in your `new` action, you are not creating an instance of `Person`, and in your view, all the fields in the form will be empty. But in the `create` action, your have `@person` (that doesn't have the `pwd` method) which is sent to view to be rendered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you're not getting the validation errors because you are not checking for them in your view. When validation fails, the error messages are added to an errors hash associated with the object you were trying to save. To optionally display them, add something similar to this to your view:

```
<% form_for :person, @person, :url => persons_url, :html=>{:method=>:post} do |f| %>
  <% if @person.errors.any? %>
    <ul id="errors">
    <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
      <li>
        <%= error %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

Rest of your form goes here...
```